# Should you use gasoline on cylinder head gasket

Tags: engine, gasoline, camshaft, cylinder-head

I'm an amateur mechanic.
Recently I met an experienced car mechanic and he told me that if I dip a new out of the box cylinder head in gasoline mixed with engine oil for a couple of hours, it would last a lot longer than usual. I wanted to know if there's anyone who had experience about this and or if he was just messing with me!?

Thanks for the time you took to answer my question; And I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! In my 35+ years of wrenching, this is nothing I've ever heard of before. I think if Felpro wanted this done, they'd have it done from the factory. I would NEVER do this to my gaskets. ANY of my gaskets.

Comment: Thanks @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I would be more than happy to use your opinion when I'm working and yes I wouldn't do that to my gaskets either I just wanted make sure I'm not missing out on something.

Comment: I left this as a comment because maybe someone knows better than I do ... There are a couple of people who've been around for awhile who might have an idea where this comes from and the reasons why someone might be doing it in the first place. I would NOT be one of them.

Comment: Sounds like grandpa's folklore to me, like storing a car battery on wood. Gasoline will damage the valve seals if its a fully assembled head.

Comment: As you specify gasket in the question title, I would not wash a new gasket in gas as some gaskets are pre-treated with products to help the seal.